# Fantasy title where MC is a male wizard, who is charmed by a female humanoid creature (troll?)

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for some help finding a fantasy novel I remember reading some time ago. Maybe middle school, pre-2007?

I cannot remember any of the overarching main plot, just the romantic subplot.

It starred a male mage, who encounters a female troll (or possibly some other humanoid fantasy creature). The troll is entering the time in her life where she's in heat, so is looking for a mate. but, upon encountering the male wizard, she on a whim casts her innate, natural seduction charm upon him, making him feel drawn to her.

She makes a comment, or muses, at one point that she's so uncomfortable when in heat, and can't imagine how it is for humans who are in heat all year round for the majority of their life span.

And the male mage muses that he can feel the charm she has put him under, and could easily break it if he so chose. But he decides to play along. Thus becoming more romantically attached to her.

For some reason, I want to think it's a magic the gathering novel? Or maybe a Terry Goodkind or Pratchett novel? Though that feels untrue.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/43562764-unnatural-magic matches on search parameters, bit not on actual details.

Comment: Just gave it a look-through, and that's not it unfortunately. Thanks, though!

The troll in the story I remember was much smaller than the human wizard, like hobbit-size, and they had the same sexual dimorphism between genders that humans do.

I may be misattributing the term "troll". It could be some other kind of humanoid creature.